# Parent child combo box

Tags: php, jquery, html, zend-framework

I  want to implement child parent combo box(country state like if we select any country the state combo box should be populated according to selected country) in my  form with jquery.
Please give any suggestion how to implement this
 Thanks

Comment: its pretty basic, please see jQuery change event and also look at this tutorial http://jsatt.blogspot.com/2010/01/cascading-select-boxes-using-jquery.html

Comment: i want to achive this with zend framework.

Comment: Then add Zend Framework in your tags

Comment: I took the liberty of adding zend-framework to your post

Answer (score 1):

Well, attach a function on the change event of the country combo box and fetch the html from the AJAX or similar. Then populate the child combo box.

For example

```
$("#parentbox").change(function() {
   var myval =$("#parentbox").val();
   // Fetch the content from database or similar
   $("#childbox").html(newhtml);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer..
but actually am working with zend framework and am using simple html form instead of zend form.

Comment: What is the purpose of using $("#childbox").empty(); before .html()?

Comment: How corresponding states will populated according to country
Please explain how to fetch content from database.

Comment: .html() will clear the content before populating new data.  .empty() is redundant for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This code iterates through an array, and populates another select box (#targetBox) based on your selection in #sourceBox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#sourceBox').change(function(){
    var options = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
      options += '<option>' 
          + locations[i][$('#sourceBox option:selected').text()] 
          + '</option>';
    }
    $('#targetBox').html(options);
    });
});
```